# How to find all the data of object by given id in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, object

How to find all the data of object by given id. For example this is my array of obbject:

```js
const array = [{
    "name": "max",
    "id": 10
  },

  {
    "name": "ram",
    "id": 20
  },

  {
    "name": "sita",
    "id": 30
  },

  {
    "name": "bill",
    "id": 10
  },
]
```

Now i wanna create function that returns all data that has `id` of 10. The function should return, `{"name": "max", "id": 10}` and `{"name": "bill", "id": 10}`.

I tried doing this:

```js
const array = [{
    "name": "max",
    "id": 10
  },

  {
    "name": "ram",
    "id": 20
  },

  {
    "name": "sita",
    "id": 30
  },

  {
    "name": "bill",
    "id": 10
  },
]

function findData(data, id) {
  const found = data.find(element => element.id === id)
  return found
}

console.log(findData(array, 10))
```

but the problem is, it just returns one object instead of returning all the data

Comment: use `filter`. `find` return first matching condition... `filter` returns all matching condition

Comment: The whole point of IDs is that they're unique. Maybe start there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const array = [
  { name: 'max', id: 10 },

  { name: 'ram', id: 20 },

  { name: 'sita', id: 30 },

  { name: 'bill', id: 10 }
];

function findData(data, id) {
  return data.filter(element => element.id === id);
}

console.log(findData(array, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `Array#find`

```js
const array = [ {"name": "max", "id": 10 }, {"name": "ram", "id": 20 }, {"name": "sita", "id": 30 }, {"name": "bill", "id": 10 }, ]

function findData(data, id){
    const found = data.filter(element => element.id === id)
    return found
}

console.log(findData(array, 10))
```